# How to show custom express validator error message

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-validator

I have used one controller and one model. After post form , i am checking  either email id already exist  or not. For checking email using express custom validator  in controller. Inside controller call model function in which check email using mongodb. But every time condition false. Please guide me , i am new in node js.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iflcR.png)

Comment: Show code that you tried

Comment: Not just any code, but a [mcve] please

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the express-validator already show this as a use case of custom validators:

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html

```
const { body } = require('express-validator/check');

app.post('/user', body('email').custom(value => {
 return User.findUserByEmail(value).then(user => {
  if (user) {
       return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
  }
  });
}), (req, res) => {
// Handle the request
});
```